# i am getting an error while running the below code:

Tags: json, python-3.x

The program will prompt for a location, contact a web service and retrieve JSON for the web service and parse that data, and retrieve the first place_id from the JSON. A place ID is a textual identifier that uniquely identifies a place as within Google Maps.
API End Points

To complete this assignment, you should use this API endpoint that has a static subset of the Google Data:
http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/json?
need to find Place id for :American University in Cairo

```
import json
import urllib

serviceurl = "http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/json?"
data_address = "American University in Cairo"
address_wanted = data_address

parameters = {"sensor": "false", "address": address_wanted}
paramsurl = urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters)

queryurl = serviceurl + paramsurl
print("DATA URL: ", queryurl)

data = urllib.request.urlopen(queryurl).read().decode()
print('Retrieved', len(data))


jsondata = json.loads(str(data))
print (json.dumps(jsondata, indent = 4))
place_id = jsondata["results"][0]["place_id"]
print("PLACE ID: ", place_id)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value